# Get historical spelling corrected

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone  I am posting this concern for my first time. I am writing a python script to make a program which will return standard words form. I base on rules to transform a historical text(spelling normalization). Here, the code does not work properly. It merely displays the modified word but not the entire file. Please, I ask for ideas on how to solve.

```
import re, string, unicodedata
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import spacy
import codecs

nlp = spacy.load('fr')
with codecs.open(r'/home/m16/fatkab/RD_project/corpus.txt', encoding='utf8')as f:
    word =f.read()
    tokens = re.split(r'\W+', word)
    print (tokens)

for word in tokens:
    rule1 = word.replace('y', 'i')

    # to avoid modifying y as a word itself:
    if word.endswith ('y')and len(word) >= 2:
        print(rule1)
```

my sample input:  Or puis que Dieu est ainsi descendu
      ÃƒÂ  nous,qu'il luy a pleu de nous communiquer 
ainsi sa bontÃƒÂ© : n'est ce pas raison que nous
      soyons du tout siens? Et d'autant qu'il nous a tendu
      la main pour nous racheter, ne faut-il pas que
      nous soyons son heritage, quand il nous a acquis
      par sa vertu? Le peuple donc s'il eust eu vn grain
      de prudence , deuoit bien se ranger en toute humilitÃƒÂ©
      pour receuoir la doctrine qui luy estoit
      preschee par Moyse. Et mesme quelle authorite
      meritoit la Loy , qui estoit ainsi approuuee par
      tant de miracles?Car Dieu ne commande pas simplement
      ÃƒÂ  Moyse de parler, apres l'auoir choisi
      pour son prophete:mais il le tire en la montagne,
      il le separe de la compagnie des hommes,afin que
      quand il viendra mettre en auant la Loy,qu'on le
      tienne comme vn Ange,& non point comme vne creature mortelle.

here is the output

```
lui
lui
lui
ai
oui
Loi
lui
foi
Loi
hui
soi
lui
lui
lui
ci
Loi
soi
lui
ai
lui
lui
doi
quoi
soi
ai
lui
lui
soi
# the language is French
```

Comment: Please add your code, your attempts and finally your error message or at least incorrect output. With your question we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Timat that should go [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53498130/edit). :-)

Comment: @Timat Please add your code in the post itself, not in comments.

Comment: can you also add sample input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use re.sub on the entire text.**

One major benefit of regex is that you can run a rule across large amounts of text - without having to manually tokenise and rebuild the output.

```
import re
text = "ouy you are the best luy guy in the try"
sub_pattern = re.compile(r"y(\W+|$)")
print(re.sub(sub_pattern, r"i\1", text))
# oui you are the best lui gui in the tri
```

Here we use the `re.sub` functionality to replace each match of the pattern with our replacement, across the entire file.

To maintain the spaces between the lines - we use the backreference `\1` in the replacement pattern. This adds the text from capture group (1) in the match, back into the output.

**Regex patterns explained:**

`re.compile` - if you're using the same regex over and over, compiling it once saves the machine having to keep re-computing it. In this case, it's just used to separate that regex onto it's own line for clarity.

`r"y(\W+|$)"` - the `r` tells python to treat the string as raw, that is backslashes will not escape characters incorrectly. To match the "y"s at the end of strings, the rule is "a 'y' followed by non-word characters, or the end of the string ($)". This is the pattern we use to match all the "incorrect" 'y' endings in the input. Note that the whitespace is captured in a group `()` so we can use it in the backreference later.

`r"i\1"1` - First we want to replace the matched y+whitespace with an "i" as per your rules. Then, we need to ensure we put the whitespace back in - which we do with the backreference `\1` which adds whatever content was captured by group1 in our pattern `(\W+|$)`.

---

**Alternatively**

Instead of capturing the whitespace, replacing it and adding it back in. We can also use a non-capturing group in the original pattern - so we only capture the "y" and replace it.

For this you could use the pattern:

```
sub_pattern = re.compile(r"y(?=\W+|$)")
print(re.sub(sub_pattern, r"i", text))
# oui you are the best lui gui in the tri
```

Note that the whitespace matching pattern is now prepended with `?=` which denotes it is a non-capturing lookahead. This means it will check that these characters exist after the "y" but it does not remove them from the string during the replacement. As such, the replacement only needs to replace with "i" as the whitespace will not be modified.

Comment: This is very useful! thank so much for your great assistance, however, I have a question regarding other modifications.How to use regex when the character to be changed is located in the middle of the word and also concerns many words from different lemmas such us 'sauuage,gouuernement ,inuoque etc where I need to turn one 'u' into 'v'. since I am not good at regex I was proceeding individually.

Comment: @Timat Often the easiest solution will be to create a number of separate rules that solve individual/specific issues (such as ending y -> i) and then running them one after another (rather than trying to make a single regex pattern to solve everything). For your 'uu' rule for example you might simply replace all 'uu' with 'v', or even check something like `(?=\w)uu(?=\w)` if you want to ensure the 'uu' has at least one letter before&after it. If you're still unsure, please just ask as a separate question, and mark this as accepted if it has solved the issue you originally posted.